# How can I fix the topology of a heptagon?

Tags: subdivision-surface, topology

I've modeled the following screw on which I have applied a subdivision. I managed to fix most of its bad topologies, but I can't wrap my head around the following scenario. I have this heptagon that I want to convert to quads and I have been googling for help for the past two hour without success. I just don't understand how to fix this.

I am assuming I need to convert the heptagon to quads, but I might be wrong.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you add your blend file so I can play with the geometry?  ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help)) Meanwhile, do you have autosmooth on?  You should be able to get away with geometry similar to what you have

Comment: Oh, I didn't knew I could upload blend files. Here it is: https://blend-exchange.com/b/gkDrvMeN/

Comment: Wow, that is indeed a rough problem.  I can add geometry that moves the issue around but I can't really come up with a way to fix it.

Comment: Yes, this is very strange. Even if I extend the three lines to the next side of the screw, the hollows keep appearing at the same place... even though I make the twist more prominent. Thanks for having took a look at it!

Answer (score 7):

This kind of topology works fine in my opinion but I got rid of all your modifiers (not sure how they are useful):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Faster again. I'm not even surprised anymore :)

Comment: thanks but I'm not sure if I'm good as I don't understand what all these modifiers are for  ;)

Comment: They add bevels to the screw's edges by using vertex groups. Otherwise the edges become smooth like on your screenshot. I do that to keep my model low-poly.

Answer (score 7):

I usually work around it with non-square quads.
It works reasonably well with the Subdivision Modifier.

[image]